# What type of C# object does the following JSON map to?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to desalinize the following JSON into a strongly typed C# object:

```
{"myThings":{"One thing":"aaaaa","Two thing":"bbbbb"}}
```

*One thing* and *Two thing* aren't always called *One thing* and *Two thing*, these change every time, and there could be more or less myThings.

I can't figure out what type of object **myThings** should be, I am thinking a KeyValuePair but am unsure if Json.Net supports deserialising to a key/value pair, or if this is even correct. Can somebody confirm?

Thanks

Comment: could be bound to various (combination of) datatypes... List, dictionary, List of dictionaries, ...

Comment: This sounds like a question where you should just test it to find out if it works or not

Comment: Just go to the [Json2CSharp web site](http://json2csharp.com) and post your JSON and have it generate your C# class(es) for you ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyThings
{
    public string OneThing { get; set; }
    public string TwoThing { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
class MyThings
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

If the number of "X things" is unknown and variable use the `Dictionary<string, string>`. If you are always going to have `{"One thing":"aaaaa","Two thing":"bbbbb"}` use the first class.

**EDIT:**
Given your edit, use the `Dictionary<string, string>`